# Creating factories for Django models with OnetoOne relationships

Tags: python, django, factory, one-to-one, factory-boy

I'm trying to setup a number of factories for Django models which have a OneToOne relationship & they don't seem to behave in the same way as foreign keys.

When running my unittest the main model doesn't have it's relationships set.

My models:

```
class ThePlan(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User")
    creationdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class OldPlan(models.Model):
    plan = models.OneToOneField("ThePlan")
    theplan = CharField(max_length  = 200,)


class NewPlan(models.Model):
    plan = models.OneToOneField("ThePlan")
    theplan = CharField(max_length  = 200,)
```

My factories:

```
class ThePlanFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = "mysite.PlanModel"

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)


class OldPlanFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = "mysite.OldModel"

    plan = factory.RelatedFactory(ThePlanFactory)
    theplan = ''


class NewPlanFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = "mysite.NewModel"

    plan = factory.RelatedFactory(ThePlanFactory)
    theplan = ''
```

And in my test `setUp()` I'm doing the following;

```
def setUp(self):
    self.user = factories.UserFactory.create()

    self.plan = factories.ThePlanFactory.create(
        user=self.user
    )
    self.oldplan = factories.OldPlanFactory.create(
        plan=self.plan
    )
    self.newplan = factories.NewPlanFactory.create(
        plan=self.plan
    )
```

So when I'm running a test with this included I'm getting `DoesNotExist: ThePlan has no OldPlan`.

Where am I going wrong here? Is the problem that I'm calling `create` immediately and instead I should setup the factories with `build`, set the relationships, and then call `save`?

Comment: @danihp well spotted! I was writing it out as `main`, `model1`, `model2` and realised that was a boring example so changed mid-way through & missed that one! thanks.

Comment: It seems a problem with `ThePlanFactory` but `OldPlanFactory`. Can you tell us where (what line of setUp) raises error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my issue was related to time and the creation of the 2 dependant factories.

Instead of calling create on them straight away, I instead set them up and saved the objects once the `plan` relationship had been set. The following works as I need it to;

```
def setUp(self):
    self.user = factories.UserFactory.create()

    self.plan = factories.ThePlanFactory.create(
        user=self.user
    )
    self.oldplan = factories.OldPlanFactory()
    self.oldplan.plan = self.plan
    self.oldplan.save()

    self.newplan = factories.NewPlanFactory()
    self.newplan.plan = self.plan
    self.newplan.save()
```